# How do I send and receive simultaneously with netcat?

Tags: unix, netcat

I need to test a TCP server by connecting with netcat as a client sending a stream from /dev/random and at the same time pipe the output to /dev/null.

Receiving:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 3000 > /dev/null
```

Sending:

```
cat /dev/random | nc 127.0.0.1 3000
```

How can I do both at same time?

I can only connect one client and I need to pipe output to /dev/null for fast consumption of the output (~50MB/s).

Answer (score 1):

Use `nc 127.0.0.1 3000 >/dev/null &` to send that command to background. Then you can run the other command. Check the `jobs` commands as well as `fg` and `bg` to see how to switch foreground and background jobs.

Comment: No, this would not work. I need to send to stdin of netcat and pipe stdout of same netcat process to /dev/null.

Comment: `netcat` can open only 1 network connection. For a client/server model, you need 2 processes. See the example on the manpage at http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

Comment: Not looking for more than one connection. In this case server by design is restricted to only one client at a time. Since, the TCP connection is bidirectional, and I am trying to send random bytes to the server while consuming everything it sends to the client as fast as possible.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for the `echo` service. Check your /etc/inetd.conf or xinetd.conf, `echo` is usually disabled. `chargen` is also a nice thing to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this works:

```
cat /dev/random | netcat 127.0.0.1 3000 > /dev/null
```

Comment: `>/dev/null` is much shorter.